# Can i follow a facebook page via graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to develop a Facebook App and I would like to follow a Facebook Page through the Graph API with the user access token.

Comment: may i ask what for? users can just go to the page and like or follow it, so the feature is already there. i am pretty sure there is no api for it.

Comment: No, that is not possible via API.